# outlining text in processing

Tags: processing, processing.js

My goal is to obtain an outline of text that is 1 pixels wide.

It could look something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/Lk1ju9yw/

I can't think of a good way to go about this so I did the following (in pseudocode):

```java
PImage img;

void setup() {
  size(400, 400);    
  // use text() to write on the canvas
  // initialize PImage img
  // load pixels for canvas and img
  // loop thru canvas pixels and look for contrast
  for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
      // compare canvas pixels at x-y with its neighbors
      // change respective pixel on PImage img so as not to disturb canvas
    }
  }
  // update pixels and draw img over the canvas
  img.updatePixels();
  img(img, 0, 0);
}
```

In a nutshell, I wrote white text on a black background on the canvas, did some edge detection and drew the results on a PImage, then used the PImage to store the results. I guess I could have skipped the PImage phase but I wanted to see what the edge detection algorithm produced.

So this does a decent job of getting the outline but there are some problems:

1. The outline is sometimes 1+ pixels wide. This is a problem. Suppose I want to store the outline (ie. all the positions of the white pixels) in an ArrayList.

For example, if using the ArrayList I draw an ellipse at EVERY point along the outline, the result is ok. But if I want the ellipses spaced apart, the ellipse-outline becomes kind of rough. In the fiddle I provided, the left edge of the letter 'h' is 2 pixels wide. Sometimes the ellipse will be drawn at the inner pixel, sometimes at the outer. That kind of thing makes it look ugly.

2. Elements of the ArrayList might be neighbors in the ArrayList, but not on the PImage. If I want to draw a circle for every 10th ArrayList location, the result won't necessarily be spaced apart on the PImage.

Here is an example of how ugly it can be: https://jsfiddle.net/Lk1ju9yw/1/

I am quite sure I understand why this is happening. I just don't know how to avoid it.

I also believe there is a solution (a PFont method) in p5.js. I am comfortable using p5 but unless I have to (let's say, because of difficulty), I would rather use processing. I've also heard of some libraries in processing that can help with this. Partly, I am interested in the result, but I am also interested in learning if I can program a solution myself (with some guidance, that is).

Answer (score 0):

You can get an outline of text very easily in P5.js, because text honors the fill and stroke colors. So if you call `noFill()` the text will not be filled in, and if you call `stroke(0)` the text will have a black outline.

```js
function setup() { 
  createCanvas(400, 200);
  noSmooth();
} 

function draw() { 
  background(220);
 
  textSize(72);
  textAlign(CENTER);
 
  noFill();
  stroke(0);
 
  text("hey", width/2, height/2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.16/p5.js"></script>
```

Unfortunately this approach won't work in regular Processing, because it just uses the stroke color for text. I'm not totally sure about Processing.js, but my guess is it's the same as Processing.

If you draw this to a buffer (using `createGraphics()`), then you can iterate over the buffer to get a list of points that make up your outline.

Now, as for putting the points in the correct order, you're going to have to do that yourself. The first approach that occurs to me is to sort them and group them by letter.

For example, your algorithm might be:

1. Find the upper-left-most point. Add it to your list.
2. Does that point you just added have any neighbors? If so, pick one and add it to your list. Repeat this step until the point has no neighbors.
3. Are there any points left? If so, find the point closest to the one you just added, and add it to your list. Go to step 2.

This might not be perfect, but if you want something more advanced you might have to start thinking about processing the list of points: maybe removing points that have a left neighbor, for example. You're going to have to play around to find the effect you're looking for.

This was an interesting question., thanks for that. Good luck, sounds like a fun project.